# Ubuntu installer wont load

Tags: 14.10

I trashed a computer and wanted to put ubuntu on it. I booted it up via a flash drive and my computer said: "boot error". how do I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably it might be flash drive error try to reconfigure it.How did You make your bootable flash drive?

Comment: perhaps you can expand this to show how you could "reconfigure it"? what do you mean by "flash driver error"?

Comment: its file system fat....................................................................